# What is the meaning of null regression coefficients

Tags: statistics, least-squares, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials, linear-regression

I have real data $x(t)$ which I model using the linear regression model: $\displaystyle f(t)= \sum_{i=0}^n c_i \phi_i(t)$, where $c_i$ are the regression coefficients I'm trying to find and $\phi_i(t)$ are a basis function (I chose Legendre Polynomials for their orthogonality).

I noticed something strange I couldn't explain i.e. when I fix $n=1$ for my model I get $\hat{c}_0, \hat{c}_1$, normal! Then when I fix $n=2$ for my model I get $\hat{c'}_0=\hat{c}_0, \hat{c'}_1=\hat{c}_1, \hat{c'}_2=0$ (Seems like $n=2$ didn't add anything to the data modeling!)

What is more strange is that when I fix $n=3$, I get $\hat{c''}_0, \hat{c''}_1, \hat{c''}_2, \hat{c''}_3$ that are completely different (no $\hat{c''}_2=0$)

Does anyone understand what is happening here?

This also happens for other even index coefficients $c_4, c_6, \dots$ i.e. when they are the latest regression coefficient in my model they are null but when I add another odd index coefficient they are not. Also I noticed that the coefficient values I obtain are high (as if to indicate an overfitting!)

Comment: Can you list the coefficients so we see, for example, if they just look like a change of basis from Legendre polynomials to odd degree powers of x (or something like that)?

Comment: here are the coeff. wrt $n$: ($n=1: \hat{c}_0=-47.85, \hat{c}_1=-29.08$), ($n=2: \hat{c'}_0=-47.85, \hat{c'}_1=-29.08, \hat{c'}_2 = 0.00$), ($n=3: \hat{c''}_0=-2.26\times 10^3, \hat{c''}_1=-2.44\times 10^3, \hat{c''}_2 = -1.14\times 10^3, \hat{c''}_3 = -0.22\times 10^3$)

Comment: thanks.  can you write out what the polynomial approximation to f(t) is at each value of n  (the $\sum c_i \phi_i (t)$), to see if it is converging to anything?

Comment: my f(t) has more than 10000 points! I don't think I can do that!

Comment: What I noticed is that I can recover good enough the form of my real data using $n=3$ but not $n=2$ or $n=1$.

Comment: For each n your approximation is a polynomial of degree n.   I mean what are the polynomials for the first few values of $n$  (as many as you are willing to list).  The coefficients may show some patterns.

Comment: Here are my basis functions (up to third degree):
$\phi_0(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \phi_1(t) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} (\frac{2t}{T} - 1), \phi_2(t) = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} (\frac{3}{2}{(\frac{{2t}}
{T} - 1)^2} - \frac{1}{2}),{\phi _3}(t) = \sqrt {\frac{7}{2}} (\frac{5}{2}{(\frac{{2t}}{T} - 1)^3} - \frac{3}{2}(\frac{{2t}}{T} - 1))$.

$T$ is my data duration. I basically scaled and shifted the Legendre Polynomials to get orthogonal polynomials on the duration of my data instead of the original $(-1,1)$ interval

Comment: Also my data is a time series, my independent variable (time) $t\in[0, T]$ if this might help

Comment: OK, but what is $\sum_1^n c_i \phi_i(t)$ for the values of $n$ that you computed?  This is your approximation to f(t) and is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.  What are its coefficients?  That should be computable from the c_i that you listed above.  And then you can see if the coefficients of the approximations are stabilizing.

Comment: Is this what you mean:
$f_1(t) = -9.69t-18.77=f_2(t)$, 
$f_3(t) = -20.37t^3-6.6t^2-113.33t-740=f_4(t)$,
$f_5(t) = -2.6t^5+13.5t^4-33.33t^3+25t^2-133.33t-740=f_6(t)$

Comment: Yes, assuming that by $t$ you mean $t/T$.

Comment: I supposed $T=6$ seconds for simplification, sorry for not mentionning it

Comment: what do we gain from knowing they stabilized? Does this indicate that the coefficients that stabilized are the ones meaningful for the regression and others not?

Comment: If you can just tell me what's the best way to generate results that allow us to draw the wanted conclusions I'll do it!

Comment: Actually, writing in terms of x = 2(t/T) - 1  is what we want, and might eliminate or reduce the coefficient variation (of the $f_n(t)$ with $n$).  Legendre polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the least-squares distance on [-1,1] but not on [0,1].

Comment: Yes, I did the change of variable $x = \frac{2t}{T}-1$ so make sur these polynomials $\phi_i(t)$ are orthogonal on $[0, T]$

Comment: ok, I'll do it.

Comment: $f_1(x) = - 29.08*x - 47.85 = f_2(x) $,

$f_3(x) = - 550*x^3 - 1710*x^2 - 2110*x - 1690 = f_4(x)$,

$f_5(x) = - 630*x^5 - 2056.25*x^4 - 2825*x^3 - 2212.5*x^2 - 1425*x - 1351.25 = f_6(x)$,

$f_7(x) = - 1345.99*x^7 - 4042.5*x^6 - 3495.71*x^5 + 544.69*x^4 + 1997.44*x^3 + 276.22*x^2 - 771.84*x - 731.21 = f_8(x)$

Answer (score 1):

The Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, but your regression results (by changing) show that their values on your data have nonzero covariance.

If $f(t)$ is odd that would explain the odd/even pattern with the $c_i$, where the even degree $c_{2n}$ contribute nothing on their own, but are involved in isolating the contribution of odd powers of $x$.

Comment: what do you mean by nonzero covariance? Since I have different real data measurements for which I use this model, I noticed also that the regression coefficients I'm estimating are a lot correlated (they are linear combinations of each other)! Is this a consequence of this nonzero covariance?

Comment: Also what is it you mean by "isolating the contribution of odd powers of $x$"?

Comment: If f(t) is an odd function then adding the next higher even-degree polynomial to the regression will not change the regression output. However there is a unique linear combination of the c_i (of all degrees, even and odd, up to 2k+1, for a fixed value of k) that has a given set of coefficients for odd powers of x, and zero for all the even degree powers.

Comment: Nonzero covariance = ($\phi_i(t)$ and $\phi_j(t)$ are correlated, on the set of $t$ used in the regression).

Comment: can $phi_i(t)$ and $\phi_j(t)$ be correlated but orthogonal?

Comment: Yes. They are orthogonal with respect to a quadratic form that is different from, but approximated by, the least-squares distance in the regression.

Comment: I admit I'm overwhelmed by all this and can't understand. Is there any material you advise me to learn, or check, to be able to understand all these relationships between odd and even indices regression coefficients, correlation and orthogonality between basis functions, etc.? Thanks for your help and effort.